# Simple way to modify XML in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, gdataxml

I get an XML file with a huge amount of data. I would like to add some entries to it. I have looked at GDataXML and a few others but cant seem to find something that will allow me to add entries without having to fully map the XML and then reconstruct it. What is a simple way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have looked at `GDataXML` and don't want to go for it, then [`TouchXML`](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML) could be a nice alternative. Here is a good tutorial on how to use TouchXML [here](http://dblog.com.au/general/iphone-sdk-tutorial-building-an-advanced-rss-reader-using-touchxml-part-1/).